# Can a 12V 7AH@ C20 battery support a motor having load variations form 1-10 Amps?

Tags: batteries, dc, dc-motor, maximum-ratings, current-rating

I want to know what is the significance of C5, C10, C20 rated  7AH Battery to drive a varying load 12V DC Motor. Is it possible for a C20 Battery to power the motor for atleast 20Mins or so if the motor takes a load of 5-10Amps. Or is it like 7/20A is the max load capacity for C20 7AH battery.
Thanks for any useful information

Comment: Amp hour capacity help you figure out the energy capacity, "C" rating helps you figure out the possible *power* or *rate* of energy.  Do the math - though keep in mind you probably can't get the full rated energy capacity at higher discharge rates.

Comment: Can you make the point.? I read about C rating around. i need to know if 7AH C20 battery can provide 1-5Amps if load requires it. I already know it is designed to give out 7/20=.35Amps for 20Hr.

Comment: You seem to be trying to apply the C rating backwards.  A 7 AH cell rated 1C can theoretically provide 7 amps, one rated 10C can theoretically provide 70 for a shorter time, etc.  But don't assume ratings on cheap cells from dubious suppliers are real, and things like wiring, contacts, and overload circuits can be limits to.

Comment: Ok. Can u give me relevant information